# Colocar o ID na tabela chave estrangeira

Tags: php, html, mysql

Porque não consigo colocar o **ID** na minha tabela *chave estrangeira* `last_insert_id()` retornando "0"

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<title>cadastrando</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$saldo=$_POST['saldo'];
$limiteSaqueDiario=$_POST['limiteSaqueDiario'];
$flag=$_POST['flag'];
$tipoConta=$_POST['tipoConta'];
$dataCriacao=$_POST['dataCriacao'];

$nome="nome";
$cpf="cpf";
$dataNascimento="dataNascimento";

$sql="insert into pessoa (nome,cpf,dataNascimento) value ('$nome','$cpf','$dataNascimento')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$sqlconta="insert into conta (idPessoa,saldo,limiteSaqueDiario,flag,tipoConta,dataCriacao) value (last_insert_id(),'$saldo','$limiteSaqueDiario','$flag','$tipoConta','$dataCriacao')";
$result=mysql_query($sqlconta);


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lembrando que as funções `mysql` estão obsoletas

Comment: Fácil, seu SQL está dando erro ao inserir `pessoa` e por isso não há ID para inserir em `conta` ;)

Comment: tenho 2 tabelas uma conta e outra pessoa quero colocar o idpessoa na minha tabela conta ja fiz a chave porem não esta inserindo quando coloco a função last_insert_id() ele da 0 na minha tabela que fica achava estrangeira idpessoa na tabela conta